# How do I optimize this chain of associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an `Event` model with a `many-to-many` association with a `Service` model

A user can create an event and choose what services are tagged to that event.

A user can subscribe to a service, and when an event gets created the user should be notified if the user has subscribed to a service that was tagged in that event.

In addition, the `User` model has a `has_many` association to an `Email` model.

I'd like to be able to get an array of all the email addresses so I can send a notification to the subscribers.

Here's what I have:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :event_services, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :services, :through => :event_services

  def recipients
    recipients = services.each_with_object(arr = []) do |service|
      service.users.each do |user|
        user.emails.each do |email|
          arr << email.address
        end
      end
    end
  end
  recipients.uniq
end
```

This works, but its super ugly and not very efficient. How would I go about optimizing this?

Here's my Email model:

```
class Email < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :address, :user_id  
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be more efficient with a single SQL request The following request, using [multiple joins](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables), should work:

```
def recipients
  Email.joins(:user => {:services => :event_services}).where(:event_services => {:event_id => self.id}).pluck(:address).uniq
end
```

Comment: I like this approach, building a query on the Email model. But I don't have a users association on Email. Email has a belongs_to association on User.

Comment: To be specific, I get this error: `ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError: Association named 'users' was not found; perhaps you misspelled it?`

Comment: There may be a typo, I don't have your complete model. Try to split the query to isolate the erroneous part. Start checking that `Email.joins(:users)` is ok, etc... The Rails Query guide may help you for the syntax.

Comment: It should be `Email.joins(:user)`

Comment: Perfect! As a quick aside, I was able to solve this another way. `services.scoped.joins(:users => :emails).pluck(:address).uniq`